# My cat is dead vs my cat was dead

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I wanted to tell someone that my cat"is dead or was dead"i got flustered between the present or the past

Comment: Did it come back to life? Because unless it did, "is dead" is the only correct answer.

Comment: _is dead_ is relative to the current time.  _was dead_ is relative to some other time.  e.g., _When I came home from school on the last day of 4th grade, my mother told me that my cat **was** dead._   versus  _I'm so depressed; my cat **is** dead._

Comment: So if you're telling them now, you would say that your cat is dead.  Unless you're saying something like "Honest, officer, I didn't do it.  The cat was dead when I got here."

Comment: No,my cat didn't come back to life, thanks!!

Comment: The simple past is not "was dead" but simply "died". My cat died.

Comment: You can use the present emphatic form which would be "My cat is dead as disco."

Comment: When?  If you found the cat dead when you got home, "My cat was dead."  If you just ran over the cat with your car, "My cat is dead."

Answer (score 1):

Both predicates, states of being.

Would normally always be *is*, with the exception of [zombies].

*Is dead* - for describing your cat who is now dead and shall always therefore be dead. (See [zombie])

*Was dead* is used when that state of being is referenced with another state of being (**alive**) *at a different time*.

> My cat was dead when I got home

Note how the inverse is ungrammatical/semantically nonsensical (My cat is dead when I moved to Boston) or used ironically for comedic effect: (My cat is dead when I get home)

Answer (score -3):

In short, u use "is" when u refer to d current fact and "was" when it is in a past story or belongs to d past which does not tell any of d current situation

Comment: The fact is my cat died a year ago

Comment: Then my cat is dead.... If u wanna refer 2 d action, then use d real verb "died".... Because "dead" is an adjective and if it's d case, then of course u refer to d current state of ur cat, then "my cat is dead" is d correct one

Comment: Use of txtspeak is deprecated on this site, since it is not proper English and will therefore (fairly or otherwise) subtract from the value of your answer.

Comment: While you're not wrong, a longer, more in-depth explanation, ideally with links to supporting documentation, would make this a better answer.  Also, as @TimLymington mentioned, please use correct spelling and grammar.  See [How do I write a good answer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more info.

Comment: I see. Sorry for using informal or even weird spellings, guys. I will try not to do it anymore. Thanks a lot for the invaluable advice :)